# How to store exception and error messages in text file when scripts get failed using selenium webDriver Java

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using TestNG, Jenkins, Java and hybrid automation framework. I need to store exception and error messages in text file only for failed scripts. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: I need to create a keyword for automation framework which can store error messages in text file while scripts get failed.

Answer (score 0):

Java log4j Logger will put your exception code in log file.

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());
log.err("Put fail script name and exceptions here");
```

[Read more](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm)